# How do you use dispatch in React components with state?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm using React + Redux and have a number of child components `<IndividualValue/>` that each load a value from an API when they mount. In addition they dispatch an action which accumulates the total of these values that is displayed in another component `<TotalValues />`. However you can't call `dispatch` inside `componentDidMount`.

I am able to achieve this using `connect` and `mapDispatchToProps` but what is the correct way to do this *with Redux and Hooks*?

Key parts of my code:

```
class IndividualValue extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 0}
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    let value = axios.get(`api/{this.props.name}`).data.value;
    this.setState({value: value})
    dispatch(incrementTotalByValue(value)); // <--- ???
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.name} = {this.state.value}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

```
function TotalValues() {
  const total = useSelector((state) => state.counter.total)

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>{total}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <IndividualValue name="nick" />
    <IndividualValue name="oscar" />
    <IndividualValue name="michael" />
    <TotalValues />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Well, to start off, you're trying to use hooks (`useDispatch`) inside class components. That doesn't work. Hooks can only be used inside functional components. If you want to use class components you should wrap your component in a `connect` (`react-redux`) and get `dispatch` from your `props`. More information found in docs here: https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/connect

Comment: @nbokmans Yes this is what's confusing me, I am able to do it using mapDispatchToProps and then in `componentDidMount` I can call `this.props.incrementTotal(value)` - this even seems to be recommended. However the docs recommend using Hooks over connect now, which is why I'm wondering what the correct way to do it with hook is?

Comment: See what I mean: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o08bv5figwxfxfd/Screen%20Shot%202021-10-20%20at%205.36.33%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: The correct way to do it with hooks is to change the class component into a function component, and the `componentDidMount` into a `useEffect(() => ..., [])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that a way to achieve this is:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(null);
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

...

```
useEffect(() => {
      (async () => {
        let value = await axios.get(`api/{props.name}`).data.value;
        setValue(value)
        dispatch(incrementTotalByValue(value));
      })();
}, [])
```

I don't know if that is the recommended way to do things with hooks. It appears `useEffect` can be used in a similar way to `componentDidMount` but there are differences and it's not a drop in replacement.

Answer (score -1):

In Class Components, I usually do this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { Actions as NameActions } from "../../store/ducks/actionsHere";

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Text</h1>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data: state.data,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
  bindActionCreators(NameActions, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not use hooks - which is the preferred way now in React.